# How to group same column values together with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

First off I am sorry if my question is unclear but it is kind of difficult to really express it in one short sentence. 
Basically, I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| BookName  | BookAuthor  |
+-----------+-------------+
| A         | Arthur      |
+-----------+-------------+
| A         | Will        |
+-----------+-------------+
| B         | Jack        |
+-----------+-------------+
| B         | Jack        |
+-----------+-------------+
| B         | Charles     |
+-----------+-------------+
| A         | Will        |
+-----------+-------------+
| A         | John        |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I am looking for a SQL query that could group both BookName and BookAuthor's same values to return, for each book name, which book author has the most entries associated.

So following my example, BookName "A" would have "Will" as book author, and BookName "B" would have "Jack".

I have tried this:
`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY BookName, BookAuthor HAVING BookName = "A"`, but the result that I will get is "Arthur".

Any help appreciated; thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by name and author. In a `HAVING` clause compare the count to another aggregation by name and author in a subquery getting the count but this time filtered for the name and limited to the (a) row with the maximum count.

```
SELECT t1.bookname,
       t1.bookauthor
       FROM elbat t1
       GROUP BY t1.bookname,
                t1.bookauthor
       HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*)
                                 FROM elbat t2
                                 WHERE t2.bookname = t1.bookname
                                 GROUP BY t2.bookname,
                                          t2.bookauthor
                                 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
                                 LIMIT 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f28e1771fc27b2b575f859dbb0b7b44a)

It doesn't break ties though. But you didn't mention whether you need that and how the rules are in such a case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed. I indeed did not mention the case there would be a tie ; in such case, if I wanted the most recent entry to be shown, do I simply need to change ```ORDER BY count(*) DESC``` to ```ORDER BY count(*) DESC, date DESC``` ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not that simple because then the time had to go into the `GROUP BY` list but that would break the current groups apart.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of entry  you could use count() and group by

```
select BookName, count(*)
from my_table  
group by BookName
order by count(*)
```

if you want the one with the most entry you could use limit 1

```
select BookName, count(*)
from my_table  
group by BookName
order by count(*)
limit 1
```

and for most frequent name in each bookname you could try

```
select BookName, BookAuthor  ,  count(*)
from my_table  
group by BookNane, BookAuthor  
order by count(*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is however not what I was intending to do, as I am trying to sort of "connect" BookAuthor with BookName, in order to get the most probable book author for each book name (most probable being the one with the most entries associated to book name).

Answer (score 0):

`Select count(BookAuthor) as 'NoOfAuthAsso' from table group by BookName`

This will give you no of associated authors for each book

Comment: Hello Vivek. Thank you a bunch for your answer. I am not trying to get the number of authors for each book name, I am trying to get the name of the one author who has the most entries associated to the book name. If you look back at the table I used for example, the result I would like to get is "Will" for bookname "A" (as "Will" has 2 entries, while "Arthur" and "John" only have one), and "Jack" for bookname B).

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte_books
as
(
  select bookname,bookauthor
  ,row_number() over(partition by bookname,bookauthor order by bookname,bookauthor) as [NumOfBooks]
  from elbat
)

select a.bookname,a.bookauthor,a.NumOfBooks
from cte_books a
inner join (
             select bookname, max([NumOfBooks]) as [NumOfBooks] from cte_books group by bookname
           ) as b
on a.bookname = b.bookname
and a.[NumOfBooks] = b.[NumOfBooks]
```

Answer (score 0):

In statistics, this is called the *mode*.  One relatively simple way to do this in MySQL is with two levels of aggregation:

```
select bookname,
       substring_index(group_concat(bookauthor order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as mode_author
from (select bookname, bookauthor, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by bookname, bookauthor
     ) b
group by bookname;
```

There are some nuances to this.  If authors can have commas in their name, then a different separator is needed.  Also, if the list of authors exceeds the default maximum length for `group_concat()`, then that needs to be extended.

MySQL 8+ of course simplifies this by supporting window functions:

```
select bookname, bookauthor 
from (select bookname, bookauthor, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by bookname order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by bookname, bookauthor
     ) b
where seqnum = 1;
```

You do not say what to do in the case of ties.  This retrieves one arbitrary best author.  But changing `row_number()` to `rank()` returns all of them.